# Selecting text from a specific column in Word with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a document which is separated by section breaks.
Within each section I may have zero or one column breaks.
I want to extract the text from the first column of each section that contains 2 columns, like so:

```
For Each oSec In ActiveDocument.Sections
    iSectionStart = oSec.Range.Start
    iSectionEnd = oSec.Range.End
    i = oSec.PageSetup.TextColumns.Count
    If (2 = i) Then
      ' Update the range to only contain the text in textcolumn 1
      ' then select and copy it to a destination string
    End If
 Next oSec
```

However, the TextColumns object does not seem to have a method for returning the column contents.

Answer (score 0):

TextColums.Count is actually not specified by the number of Column Breaks. You can have 2 columns (i.e. TextColumns.Count = 2) without a single Column Break.

If you for instance create a new document, fill it with random text by typing

`=Rand(100)`

and hit enter and select Two Columns from the Layout Tab. You will notice that you get two columns over 8 pages or so where none of the pages have Column Breaks.

The Office Object Model does not provide with an option to automatically select a specific column on a specifice page within a section. If the document actually has Column Breaks you can use the Find option to find the Column Break and from there select the Range from the start of the page to the start of the Column Break character that you just found using the Find option. Not a trivial thing to do as you can see.

Comment: Much less trivial than I expected!

Comment: I don't need to worry about the column break ambiguity you describe, however. The source document is guaranteed to have the format Language1 + ColumnBreak + Language2 + SectionBreak when viewed in draft mode.

Answer (score 0):

Since the column break marker is represented by the ASCII value 14, all I had to do was look at each word in the section until I found the expected marker

```
Sub ExtractColumnText()
'
' On pages with no columns, the text is copied to both output files
' On pages with two columns, the column1 text is copied to "C:\DocTemp\Italian.doc"
'                            and column2 text is copied to "C:\DocTemp\English.doc"
'
Dim DestFileNum1 As Long
Dim DestFileNum2 As Long
Dim strDestFile1 As String
Dim strDestFile2 As String
Dim strCol1 As String
Dim strCol2 As String
Dim i As Integer

Dim oSec As Section
Dim oRngCol1 As Range
Dim oRngCol2 As Range
Dim oRngWord As Range

strDestFile1 = "C:\DocTemp\Italian.doc" 'Location of external file
DestFileNum1 = FreeFile()
strDestFile2 = "C:\DocTemp\English.doc" 'Location of external file
DestFileNum2 = DestFileNum1 + 1
Open strDestFile1 For Output As DestFileNum1 
Open strDestFile2 For Output As DestFileNum2

For Each oSec In ActiveDocument.Sections
    Set rngWorking = oSec.Range.Duplicate
    Set oRngCol1 = rngWorking.Duplicate
    oRngCol1.End = rngWorking.End - 1   ' exclude the page break
    Set oRngCol2 = oRngCol1.Duplicate
    If 2 <= oSec.PageSetup.TextColumns.Count Then
        'examine each word in the section until we switch columns
        For Each rngWord In rngWorking.Words
            ' 14 = column break marker
            If 14 = AscW(rngWord.Text) Then             
                oRngCol1.End = rngWord.Start
                oRngCol2.Start = rngWord.End
                GoTo Xloop
            End If
        Next rngWord
    End If
Xloop:   
    oRngCol1.Select
    Print #DestFileNum1, oRngCol1.Text
    oRngCol2.Select
    Print #DestFileNum2, oRngCol2.Text
Next oSec
Close #DestFileNum1
Close #DestFileNum2
MsgBox "Done!"
End Sub
```